# Choose the volume for xmit file generated with the XMIT command

Tags: zos, mvs

I'm using the XMIT command to archive a dataset. But I can't choose the volume of the xmit file.
The dataset I'm archiving is on a specific volume and I want the xmit archive on the same volume but there is no such option to acheive that.

I use this command on z/OS UNIX:

```
    /bin/tsocmd "XMIT N1.USER DA('"DATASET.TO.ARCHIVE"') OUTDATASET('"DATASET.TO.ARCHIVE.XMIT"') NOLOG"
```

Comment: Looking at the command, you can specify OUTDD or OUTFILE to refer to a pre-allocated file for the output.

If you issue the command using JCL and IKJEFT01, you could pre-allocate the XMIT file in the JCL using IEFBR14 and whichever volume you like?

I've just tried this with a pre-allocated file and it worked.

Comment: @James, please write this comment as an answer. I was going to write the same thing based on just the subject line, but I see you've already done it. I've had to pre-allocate XMIT targets before due to bad estimates of the space required using the defaults.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you for this.
Yes you can write this as an answer @James :)

Comment: I've not had to do this myself, BUT I've been doing an SMP/E install where the sysprogs are VERY particular about which volumes I use. So I've been having a lot of "just put this on THIS volume and no other" fun lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the command, you can specify OUTDD or OUTFILE to refer to a pre-allocated file for the output. If you issue the command using JCL and IKJEFT01, you could pre-allocate the XMIT file in the JCL using IEFBR14 and whichever volume you like? I've just tried this with a pre-allocated file and it worked.